# Scala: for loop until condition

Tags: scala, for-loop, conditional-statements

How can I run `for` until a condition is met? Instead of using `scala.util.control.Breaks.break`, is it possible to test for a condition within `for`?

```
for(line <- source.getLines) {
        if (line.equals("")) scala.util.control.Breaks.break
        Console print "Message> "
        dataWriter.write(line, InstanceHandle_t.HANDLE_NIL)
      }
    } catch  {
        case e: IOException =>{
```

Comment: You should use `takeWhile` like this: `for(line <- source.getLines.takeWhile{_ != ""})`

Comment: Thanks @senia ! Is it safe to use `!=` to compare `String`s, instead of `!equals("")`?

Comment: Yes. In `scala` `==` is a null-safe equivalent of `equals` (it calls `equals`). There is another operator for reference equality (and you don't need it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `takeWhile`

```
for(line <- source.getLines.takeWhile(!_.isEmpty)) {
  Console print "Message> "
  dataWriter.write(line, InstanceHandle_t.HANDLE_NIL)
}
```

or

```
source.getLines.takeWhile(!_.isEmpty).foreach {
  line => 
   Console print "Message> "
   dataWriter.write(line, InstanceHandle_t.HANDLE_NIL)
}
```